# Cookie is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have a problem with cookie.When using this i have got an error like this

```
TypeError: $.cookie is not a function [Break On This Error] $('#' + $.cookie("activediv")).parent().parent().addClass('menuHeaderActive');
```

javascript file is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var checkCookie = $.cookie("activediv"); 
   ///$('#' + $.cookie("activediv")).parent().parent().addClass('menuHeaderActive');
   alert("a"); 
});
```

I have the plug in for this cookie.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you include jQuery JS in your `<head>`

Comment: do you have code? then show it! otherwise whatever you have posted is of no use for solving an issue

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't loaded the [Jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). If you want to use that plugin you'll need to download the js file and link it in your HTML (after the main jQuery file)

Comment: Then put your HTML in the question